# Why does it has 3 errors??? What errors did i make?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, filereader

```
import java.io.*;
public class FileApi extends File{
FileWriter fw;
FileReader fr;
PrintWriter pr;

class public FileApi (String s) throws Exception
{
    super(s);
    pw = new PrintWriter(fw = new FileWriter(s, true));

}

public void createFile() throws IOException
{
    FileApi fa = new FileApi.createFile();          
    pw.println(fa);         
}

public void createFile(String s) throws IOException
{
    File fail = new File(s);                        
    pw = new PrintWriter(fail);                     
}

public void WriteFile(String s) throws IOException
{
    pw.println(s);
    pw.flush();
}

public String readFile() throws Exception
{
    super(s);
    fr = new FileReader(new File(s));
    String str="";
        int st;

        while ((st = fr.read() )!= -1) {
            char ch=(char) st;
            str=str+ch;
        }
        return str;
}

public void close() throws IOException
{
    pw.close();
    fr.close();
    fw.close();
}

public static void main(String [] arg) throws Exception
{
    FileApi fileapi = new FileApi("greeting.txt");
    if(fileapi.exists())
    {
        System.out.println("File exists!");
        fileapi.writeFile("Putrajaya");
    }
    System.out.println(fileapi.readFile());
    fileapi.close();
}
```

}

Output:

FileApi.java:11: error:  expected
        class public FileApi (String s) throws Exception
FileApi.java:11: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
        class public FileApi (String s) throws Exception
FileApi.java:68: error: reached end of file while parsing }

Comment: As an addition to the answers below change  the variable name pw inside the constructor to pr

Comment: i can feel with the compiler and fail to parse your code. `super(s)`should only be called as first statement in your constructor, not in a method (`readFile()`) `createFile()`is another failure, ...

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong syntax for the constructor.  It should be this:

```
public FileApi (String s) throws Exception {
    super(s);
    pw = new PrintWriter(fw = new FileWriter(s, true));
}
```

(The `class` keyword at that point is incorrect, and it is confusing the parser so much that it cannot give a decent explanation of what you have done wrong.)

---

While we are on the subject of errors, it is a major mistake to declare a method or constructor as throwing `Exception`.  It makes it difficult to do sane exception handling if something is declared a "throws any exception you care to imagine".

And this:

```
    pw = new PrintWriter(fw = new FileWriter(s, true));
```

is just gratiutous, IMO.  It is far more readable if you write it as two statements:

```
    fw = new FileWriter(s, true);
    pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
```

Finally, you have declared the `PrintWriter` as:

```
    PrintWriter pr;
```

when it should really be:

```
    PrintWriter pw;
```

Comment: I don't believe you.  You should be getting different compilation errors.  Try and fix them yourself: you will learn more that way.

Comment: im sorry, ive found it, but im still getting the same error, thanks btw :)

Answer (score 0):

A constructor shouldn't contain the `class` keyword.

Change

```
class public FileApi (String s) throws Exception
{
    super(s);
    pw = new PrintWriter(fw = new FileWriter(s, true));

}
```

to

```
public FileApi (String s) throws Exception
{
    super(s);
    pr = new PrintWriter(fw = new FileWriter(s, true));

}
```